# Make header and footer static in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

How can I make header and footer on a BlackBerry screen with scrollable content in between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make your screen out of a [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html), then you can use setTitle(Field f) and setStatus(Field f) to create the header and footer, respectively.