# Blackberry MainScreen Transitions

Tags: blackberry

While writing my first Blackberry application using Java, I am confused between inheriting from `MainScreen` and `Screen` classes.

My initial understanding was that there should be just a single `MainScreen`-derived class in an application, since we would like to define the screen title and other embellishments only once. All the rest of the screens (which are invoked on top of the `MainScreen`) should derive from `Screen`.

However, this doesn't seem to be true as I have not been able to get a screen completely cover the non-title area of the previous `MainScreen`.

Is there anything specific which I have overlooked in understanding how multiple screens in a Blackberry application should be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you [read this on BlackBerry's developer site](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Screens_508096_11.jsp)?

[And also this?](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Screen_transitions_detailed_overview_806391_11.jsp)

I do often have one and only one `MainScreen` in my application.  Other screens can derive from `Screen` or `FullScreen`.  Whether or not you **need** every screen to be a `MainScreen` depends on whether your UI design requires [things like the header (title) and footer (status) in each screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064437/119114), which `MainScreen` provides.

Are you saying that you're adding other screens, and they simply aren't taking up enough space?  If you want additional screens to occupy the full screen, I would subclass `FullScreen`, not just `Screen`.

And, you're showing new screens (after the initial `MainScreen`) with [UiApplication.pushScreen() and UiApplication.popScreen()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#pushScreen(net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen))?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are confused with classes names `MainScreen` and `Screen`. Basically `MainScreen` extends `Screen` and adds additional functionality like `Menu` management, title field, status field and has already `VerticalManager` on it. If you don't need this functionality, like you have your own better menu functionality, or you need all area for custom draw logic or something else. You have ability to extend `Screen` class otherwise I suggest you to use `MainScreen` for every screen in your app.